# Making one HTML page per chapter like in Gnu manuals

Tags: html

I am writing an online document on my website as a book. Instead of having everything on one page, I would like to have one chapter per web-page with a link pointing to the previous and next chapters at the top/bottom of the page.

Something like the way the Gnu manuals do here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/

Here is the entire manual of the Gnu c library on one page:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html

Here it is in a "serialized" form starting with the introduction. 
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Introduction.html#Introduction

Since my entire document will be inside one HTML document (exported from Org mode in Emacs, but that is probably a minor detail) how do I split the
monolithic HTML document into several little ones each linking to previous and next one.

Comment: I could not find such an application either. Instead, I wrote a script that merges html-parts to such a website. If you're interested, I put it on github https://github.com/ljmdullaart/website.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its the other way around.
Instead of splitting to multiple parts, multiple part should be joined to a single one (HTML/whatever).

A good way is to find common tag and start from there.
e:g

```
<h2 id="chapter">Chapter 8</h2>Bla bla bla
```

grep id="chapter" doc.html or grep h2 doc.html
will reveal the chapter and you can start from there. Then when you need single HTML, just concatenate it. On the prev and next then you will need some scripting to create the header links.
Steps:

1. Split your docs to chapters and sections
2. Create a standard header and footer script
3. Generate the single page versions for each chapter and sections

Other way ?
https://www.naturaldocs.org/

Answer (score 0):

The way to split the file is:

```
csplit  -k total.html '/<h[12]/' {99}
```

This will create a number of files called `xx00`, `xx01` etcetera. Normally, yout first file will contain tags like `<html>`, `header>`, `<body>` and the likes. The rest of the files will, in general, contain your different chapters and/or sections. If you want to split further, use `<h[123]` as pattern, and/or use `[Hh]` if your tags can be in capitals.

If you use my script `website02` from https://github.com/ljmdullaart/website, you will need to rename the file to something with `.html` on the end.

```
typeset -i i=0
for f in xx* ; do
    i=$i+1
    mv $f $i_ch_$i.html
done
```

will do that for less than 10 files. Note however, that even though the script is available, it is created for my personal environment and I have not made any attempt to make it suitable for general use. So, some edits may be required.